# JSON Jackson Infinite Recursion Error Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have seen this error solved with many questions in the past with 2 objects which reference each other, but I can't seem to solve it using these techniques referenced (using this line, mainly):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("day")
```

My issue is that I have 3 objects which have something of a love triangle going on. Here is (some) of the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) 
(through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->DataObjects.EmployeeShiftAllocation["shift"]->
DataObjects.Shift["day"]->DataObjects.Day["employeeShiftAllocations"]->
java.util.ArrayList[0]->DataObjects.EmployeeShiftAllocation["shift"]->DataObjects.Shift["day"]->......... etc
```

So I have an object EmployeeShiftAllocation, which references a Shift, which references a Day, which has a list of EmployeeShiftAllocations.

I applied the aforementioned suggested solution, but it did not solve the problem. I placed that statement before the declaration / initialization of the 3 aforementioned objects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried solution #3 here, and figured #1 and #2 have too many downsides. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue by using

```
@JsonIgnore
```

From the EclipseLink JPA, on the Shift object. This caused the recursive loop to break, solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using @JsonIdentityInfo which will create a reference for hibernate in the second level of serialization which will break the cycle

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the purpose of the @Entity tag? I see it's likely used with a JPA, but I've never used JPAs before. Could you recommend a way forward using your answer with a JPA?

Comment: @Entity is used with jpa , it specify your model to be an entity and mapped by a table in the database, the annotations I shared should be placed above the name of your class you are facing the problem serializing

Comment: So I added EclipseLink JAR to my buildpath to allow use of JPA stuff, but my @Entity tag is still not being recognised. "Entity cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: I found I was missing a JAR. I still have the same problem with your answer sadly Amer.